# How to convert integer index into a date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with this kind of index :

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('my_file', sep=',')
data2 = data.set_index('DT')
print(data2)

...
34146 xx zz
34147 xx zz
34148 xx zz
34201 xx zz
34202 xx zz
...
```

I know that the first three numbers are the days of the year (with 001 = 01/01/2018) and the two last numbers are the hour with time step of 30min.
I'd like to convert this index in a datetime format.
I've seen and tested a lot of scripts seen on the forum but nothing is working (and I'm a huge rookie...)
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Please share a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Post edited. Sorry but I have nothing more to explain my issu.

Comment: Taking the first row, can you explain what you want to be done with it? What are the first 3 numbers? 341?

Comment: The first 3 numbers are the day (001 is the 1st of January 2018) so 341 is the 341 day of the year. The 46 is the 46th 30min time step in a day. So I want to replace the 34146 index by the equivalent day and hour.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Look at the answer below. Please keep in mind that everybody on SO expects: "What have you tried so far?" in questions

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like:

```
import datetime

def mysterious_dt_convert(mysterious_dt):
    return ( datetime.datetime(2018,1,1)             
            + datetime.timedelta(days=int(str(mysterious_dt)[:3]))
            + datetime.timedelta(minutes=int(str(mysterious_dt)[3:])*30))

mysterious_dt_convert(34146), mysterious_dt_convert(34147)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
def func(lst):
    return [datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(a/100 - 1) + datetime.timedelta(minutes=(a%100)*30) for a in lst]

data2["Date"] = func(data2.index)
data2 = data2.set_index("Date")
data2

                     DT  x   z
0   2018-12-07 23:00:00 xx  zz
1   2018-12-07 23:00:00 xx  zz
2   2018-12-08 00:00:00 xx  zz
3   2018-12-08 00:30:00 xx  zz
4   2018-12-08 01:00:00 xx  zz
```

Hope this helps